# SqlMembershipProvider administration

Tags: c#, sqlmembershipprovider

Before I embark on writing my own solution to this issue, can anyone point me to a pre-built solution for managing standard user details when using the SqlMembershipProvider?  The solutions I have found through Google seem to either be half baked 'example solutions' or unsuitable for every day usage.

Regards
Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Peter Kellner](http://peterkellner.net) has a series of good articles on creating a Membership ObjectDataSource that uses an admin console as its primary example. You can find the most complete example at http://peterkellner.net/2006/03/02/ajaxmeetsaspnet20/.